# How to use Standard Library Header Units in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20

According to Microsoft ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160 ), it implemented P1502R1 Standard library header units for C++20:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1502r1.html
in the latest Visual Studio 2019.

So one can write, e.g.:

```
import <vector>;
```

But if I do it in my Visual Studio 2019 16.10.3 (with `/std:c++latest` switch), the following compilation error arises:

> error C7612: could not find header unit for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include\vector'

The complete command-line in Debug configuration:

```
/JMC /experimental:module /external:env:"EXTERNAL_INCLUDE" /permissive- /ifcOutput "x64\Debug\" /GS /W4 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"x64\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /MDd /std:c++latest /FC /Fa"x64\Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"x64\Debug\" /Fp"x64\Debug\Project1.pch" /diagnostics:column
```

Please help how to activate this new feature in MSVC?

Comment: What version do you have?  From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20) looks like you need 19.29 (16.10)

Comment: What are your **exact flags you are passing to the compiler**?  What is the **exact compiler version**?

Comment: Have you enabled `Properties > C/C++ > Language > Enable Experimental C++ Standard Library Modules` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I would not recomment enabling that.

Comment: @RichardCritten In a sufficiently modern version of MSVC, that is deprecated; latest turns it on.  But latest plus permissive turns it back off.  Hence above questions.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/l3elnu/current_status_of_the_standard_library_modules/